# Show that if the transitive closure can be computed in T(|V |) time then BMM can be solved in O(T(3n)) time

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Show that if the transitive closure can be computed in T(|V |) time then
BMM can be solved in O(T(3n)) time.
I didn't understand the proof in the context of building edges. I added the proof

[image]

i tried to write an example

[image]

Michael P. Kim, Editted by: Bill Kuszmaul people.csail.mit.edu/virgi/6.890/lecture3.pdf

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you did not understand?

Comment: Also, the proof seems to have been taken from some paper or similar. **Please give the original author credit for their work.**

Comment: Scribe: Michael P. Kim, Editted by: Bill Kuszmaul                                                        https://people.csail.mit.edu/virgi/6.890/lecture3.pdf

Comment: I wrote an example, now how to proceed after I have duplicated the matrices and created a graph? what is the next step?

Comment: You compute which nodes on the right are reachable from which nodes on the left. This is transitive closure, and also the product of the two matrices.